# Naive Bayes Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes

Consider the binary classification problem where class label Y ∈ {0, 1} and each training example X has 2 binary attributes X = [X1, X2] ∈ {0, 1}^2.
Assume that class priors are given P(Y = 0) = P(Y = 1) = 0.5, and that the conditional probabilities P (X1|Y ) and P (X2|Y ) are given as follows:

[image]

- Assume you want to estimate the conditional probability distribution P (Y |X1, X2) directly, without making the naive Bayes assumption. How many parameters would you need to estimate from data?
- Assume you now want to estimate the joint probability distribution P (Y, X1, X2) directly. How many parameters would you need to estimate from data?

I am confused as do we need to include all the probabilities of X1 and X2 given Y?

Comment: You need to include everything what it takes to calculate $P(Y|X_1,X_2)$